# How to get the same date result from Model.objects.create and Model.objects.get in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

Given the following Django model:

```
from django.db import models

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
```

When I create an object with following code, type of date field is unicode

```
obj = SomeModel.objects.create(date=u'2015-05-18')
```

But when I get the same object from database, type of date field will be datetime.date

```
obj = SomeModel.objects.get(pk=obj.pk)
```

I know Django will transform u'2015-05-18' to a datetime.date object automatically, but why it returns the original unicode string with Model.objects.create()? is there a way to always get datetime.date from Model.objects.create() and Model.objects.get()?

Comment: Why do you want this? If you always want to get a string, why not use a charfield rather than a datefield?

Comment: I want to input u'2015-05-18' which is part of the url, and I want to get datetime.date

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass an datetime  object to the create method:

```
from datetime import date
obj = SomeModel.objects.create(date=date(2015, 5, 18))
```

or

```
obj = SomeModel.objects.create(date=date.strftime('2015-05-18', '%y-%m-%d'))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways Django transforms the data in a model. The first, when saving the model the data is transformed to the correct data type and send to the backend. The data on the model itself is *not* changed. The second, when the data is loaded from the database, it is converted to the datatype that Django thinks is most appropriate.

This is by design: Django does not want to do any magic on the models itself. Models are just python class instances with attributes, so you are free to do whatever you want. This includes using the string `u'2015-05-18'` as a `date` or the string `'False'` to store as `True` (yeah that's right).

The database cannot store dates as arbitrary data types, so in the database it is just the equivalent of a Python `date` object. The information that it used to be a string is lost, and when loading the data directly from the database with `get()`, the data is consistently converted to the most appropriate Python data type, a `date`.